# How to make the webpage shows "loading" and change content afterwards?

Tags: django

I use the following page as example:

http://isbndb.com/book/the_new_public_health_second_edition

[image]

You can see the box "Loading Prices" when you first load the page, and it will change afterwards to show relevant information on the same box as below:

[image]

I am trying to building some price comparison engine using `django`, and I think I need to inform user that the page is now loading, rather than letting user to wait in front of a blank screen.

Can anyone tell me know to do it?

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML

```
<div id="lazyLoad"> 
   <img src="\path\to\loading.gif">
</div>
```

On successful ajax call replace the innerHTML of #lazyLoad with the formatted result.